# Rails nested forms: How to update the parent attributes from a child form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Contract` model parent that has a `Job Contract` model child. The `Contract` table is like the base table and the `Job Contract` table is the details of that base contract that can be expanded in the future.

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
 has_one :job_contract, dependent: :nullify
 after_create :create_job_application_contract

 def create_job_application_contract
  JobContract.create(contract_id: self.id)
 end
end

class JobContract < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contract, optional: true
end
```

I want to update the parent `Contract` from the child `Job Contract` form so I use nested attributes in the `Job Contract` form

```
class JobContract < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :contract, optional: true
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :contract
end

# edit.html.slim
= simple_form_for @job_contract do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :contract do |c|
   = c.input :salary
```

However, this creates a new `Contract` with every submission of the `Job Contract` form. Can I use nested attributes from the child to modify the parent? My current plan is to just use an ajax button to update the `Contract` from the `Job Contract` form

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I didn't use nesting nor Ajax.

I just put everything in the `Job Contract` form by using `attr_accessor` then update the `Contract` parent in the child's update action

```
class JobContract < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :contract, optional: true
 attr_accessor :salary
end

# edit.html.slim
= simple_form_for @job_contract do |f|
  = f.input :salary

# job_contract_controller
if @job_contract.update(job_contract_params)
  @contract.update(contract_value: @job_contract.salary)
end
```